# Django model_to_dict skips all DateTimeField when converting models

Tags: django, datetime, model

I just noticed a bug with model_to_dict that it skips all DateTimeField in the model and never convert them to the dictionary, whereas use QuerySet's values() function does not. I looked on the internet but couldn't find anyone else having the same problem. I just want to confirm that this indeed is a problem that other people has encountered and see what people do to solve it. Do everyone just avoid using model_to_dict in this case and tries to emulate the behavior using values()? Or is there a better solution? What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

Below is the out:

```
>>> member = Member.objects.get(id=1)
>>> member.create_time
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 6, 1, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> model_to_dict(member)
{'verified': True, 'name': u'John', 'email': u'', 'phone': u'', 'id': 1L, 'password': u'4e3fc0574fbcdff16c8508339e', 'verify_token': u'5d98aacaba39eb7e'}
```

As you can see 'create_time' field is not in the dictionary. I had to manually insert it:

```
>>> obj = model_to_dict(member)
>>> obj
{'verified': True, 'name': u'John', 'email': u'', 'phone': u'', 'id': 1L, 'password': u'4e3fc0574fbcdff16c8508339e', 'verify_token': u'5d98aacaba39eb7e'}
>>> obj["create_time"] = member.create_time
>>> obj
{'verified': True, 'name': u'John', 'email': u'', 'phone': u'', 'create_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 6, 1, 2, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'id': 1L, 'password': u'4e3fc0574fbcdff16c8508339e', 'verify_token': u'5d98aacaba39eb7e'}
>>>
```

EDIT:

I think I found the problem: In model_to_dict():

```
opts = instance._meta
for f in opts.fields:
    if not f.editable:
        continue
```

And my create_time field is shown as not editable. Further research indicates that auto_now_add=True will automatically make editable=False. Thus causing model_to_dict() to skip it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the cause to be auto_now_add=True, it automatically sets editable=False, which causes model_to_dict() to skip the fields

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate your issue

```
>>> pprint(model_to_dict(User.objects.get(pk=1)))
{'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 21, 10, 56, 6, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'email': u'g@o.org',
 'first_name': u'\u042d\u0434\u0443\u0430\u0440\u0434',
 'groups': [],
 'id': 1,
 'is_active': True,
 'is_staff': True,
 'is_superuser': True,
 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 26, 12, 10, 28, 834151, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'last_name': u'\u0418\u0441\u043a\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432',
 'password': u'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$n8t2YQB1MaZE$lVg5bbp22ixDNQCj7AjtzGJ3WzOUnJo24137fTOxwi4=',
 'user_permissions': [],
 'username': u'1'}
```

Comment: weird, something wrong with my django installation then? Let me post my output. What version of django are you using? Mine's version 1.4.3 final

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 

django.VERSION

(1, 4, 5, 'final', 0)

Comment: let me try upgrate django see if that fixes the problem

Comment: does create_time in your example is model field and not attribute or property?

Comment: It's a DateTimeField:
     create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: i just upgraded django to 1.5.1 final. still have the same problem. My python version is the same as your.

Comment: so I have no idea. I can only suggest you debug `model_to_dict` function and see what actually is happening.

Comment: I found the cause to be auto_now_add=True, it automatically sets editable=False, which causes model_to_dict() to skip the fields.